# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost

I have build `boost 1.66.0` from source by using the following commands.

**First**

1. Go to the directory `tools/build/`.
2. Run `bootstrap.sh`
3. Run `b2 install --prefix=PREFIX` where `PREFIX` is the directory where you want Boost.Build to be installed
4. Add `PREFIX/bin` to your PATH environment variable.

As I am using `Eclipse c++ oxygen` IDE and as the 4 step I put the path 
`/home/Hussain/boost_1_66_0/lib` in the linker `Library Search Path (-L)`

**Second**

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr &&
./b2 stage threading=multi link=shared
```

and then

```
./b2 install threading=multi link=shared
```

And added the path `/home/Hussain/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib` to the linker same as `first`.

When I compile, the code compiler without complaining. But When I run the `exe` file I get the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem?

Same process I have repeated with my earlier system using `boost1.65.1` that was working fine.

Comment: Which OS?  Linux?  You probably just need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, Linux

Comment: @G.M. I think I have already added the path as shown above

Comment: No, you've only told the linker where to look at link time.  See, for example, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable).

Comment: @G.M. I have also included the path `/home/hussain/boost_1_66_0` in eclipse